# PostgreSQL OID Image Storing with PHP

Tags: php, database, postgresql, forms

HTML

```
<form action="InsertIndex.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type="file" size="25" name="userFile" value="Upload" class="uploadFile">
  <input type="submit" value="Update" class="updateFile">
 </form>
```

Variables:

```
$uploaddir = 'me/work/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userFile']);
```

PHP:

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "INSERT INTO image VALUES (1, lo_import('$uploadfile'))");
```

I would like to insert an image inside my database, I error out with a HTTP error 500.

This is a mock up of future work but would like to get it to work at a minor level first, all help is appreciated.

Comment: did you see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.pgsqllobcreate.php ?

Comment: If your BLOBs are moderate size, it might be more convenient to use "bytea" data type (sometimes called inline LOBs). See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-bytea.php